# For each loop usage in VBA and retrieving the datas

Tags: vba, loops

I have the following data in sheet1.

```
TransId CustID  Account Stake

1       1       NP1     10
2       1       NP1     11
3       1       NP1     12
4       1       NP1     13
5       1       NP1     14
6       2       NP2     15
7       2       NP2     16
8       2       NP2     17
9       2       NP2     18
10      2       NP2     19
11      3       NP3     20
12      3       NP3     21
13      3       NP3     22
14      3       NP3     23
15      3       NP3     24
```

and the following details in sheet2.

```
Account Agent   master  SuperMaster

NP1     1       5       4
NP2     9       5       6
NP3     4       3       7
NP4     8       3       2
NP5     2       7       8
NP6     8       10      2
```

I would need to  to calculate in sheet3 that, for each customerId in table, I need to consider all the TransId and the relevant stake & Account. Then i should compare account in sheet2 and retrieve the values of agent, master and Supermaster. Therefore my final calculation in sheet3 would be,
for each CustId,  transId1(stake*agent*master*supermaster) + transId2(same as 1) and goes on until TransId5, since there are 5 transactions in CutomerId1.

Kindly guide me how do I do this in VBA ? (I am new to programming & VBA)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way to go about this is using vlookup and pivot tables.  I tried for a bit to set something up purely in vba, I know it's possible, but for me this was much easier.  This will produce a table on sheet1 that you can run a pivot table off of to produce the result you want.

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim rowCount1, rowCount2 As Integer

    rowCount1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    rowCount2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value = "Agent"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value = "Master"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G1").Value = "SuperMaster"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H1").Value = "Sum"
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 2 To rowCount1
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & x).Formula = "=vlookup(C" & x & _
        ",Sheet2!A1:D" & rowCount2 & ",2,false)"
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & x).Formula = "=vlookup(C" & x & _
        ",Sheet2!A1:D" & rowCount2 & ",3,false)"
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & x).Formula = "=vlookup(C" & x & _
        ",Sheet2!A1:D" & rowCount2 & ",4,false)"
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & x).Formula = "=product(D" & x & ":G" & x & ")"
    Next x

    End Sub
```

Then on sheet 3, using a pivot table on the data from sheet 1, you get

```
Row Labels  Sum of Sum
1             1200
2             22950
3             9240
Grand Total   33390
```